# Button and label disappear after segue

Tags: ios, swift, face-id

I am very new to swift and xcode and as I was tinkering with app-making, a ran into a problem. I am trying to create a button that switches view controllers after it authenticates my face with FaceID. This is what I have so far. When I press the button, it does authenticate, but when it segues to another window, the label and button is gone. Does anyone have an idea why? Anything helps. Thanks (:

Note: Even though the button is not visible, it is still functional. I know this because when I am in Controller2 and I tap the top left button, it completes the action. The problem is simply that it is not visible.

Controller1 on left and Controller2 on right
[image: Controller1 on left and Controller2 on right]

code:

```
@IBAction func faceIDButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let context = LAContext()

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil) {
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "To sign in") { (wasSuccessful, errorInCode) in
            if wasSuccessful {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSecondView", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** you need to modally present the vc and make it's main view transparent only the portion intact is the rect you identify the face in by this

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondVC
vc.delegate = self  //to send success of face detection 
vc.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true 
vc.definesPresentationContext = true 
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext  // modally key line
self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

also you can set these properties for the secondVC in IB or set them inside `prepareForSegue` that's triggered by `performSegue` for a show segue type

**Second** don't make a segue from the second vc to the first you need to only use

```
self.dismiss(animated:true,completion:nil)
```

**Finally** completion of `evaluatePolicy` runs in background thread , so consider this if you'll go with segue

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSecondView", sender: self) 
}
```